# Update View Model's IsSelectedProperty on clicking TextBlock inside a TreeView

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have just entered the MVVM WPF world from the world of MVP Windows Forms, and I am trying to develop an analytics program.

XAML:

```
<TreeView VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProfileViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}"
                  Header="Profiles"/>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}"
                  Header="Jobs"/>
</TreeView>
```

ProfileViewModel:

```
private Profile profile;

public string Name { get { return profile.Name; } }

private bool isSelected;
public bool IsSelected
{
    get
    {
        return this.isSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        this.isSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}

public ProfileViewModel(Profile profile)
{
    this.profile = profile;
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to set the IsSelected property in the ProfileViewModel to true when the TextBlock is selected, and false otherwise. I am aware that it is possible to raise an event as such:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" PreviewMouseUp="MouseUpHandler/>
```

But I would prefer if it automatically updates the ViewModel directly. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You *can't* 'select' a `TextBlock`... do you mean *when the `TextBlock` is focused*?

Comment: ... or do you mean *when the `TreeViewItem` is selected?*

Comment: @Sheridan Ideally, I would like to bind the ProfileViewModels with a TreeViewItem, but unfortunately in all of the examples I went through it seems like I can't bind a ProfileViewModel directly to a TreeViewItem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemCollection}" ... >
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProfileViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

This is how you use the `Style` given by @devhedgehog. The `ItemContainerStyle` of any collection control is always the `Style` for the 'container' of each item, in this case, the `TreeViewItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the TreeViewItem.IsSelected to a property in your item.

Like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsMarked}"/>
</Style>
```

Every TreeViewItem will try to bind to its coresponding item's property called IsMarked.

Try it out :)

Comment: But I'm using TargetType="TextBlock" here... but still, thanks!

Comment: TextBlock doesnt have IsSelected... Use TreeViewItem instead OR RelativeSource Binding.

Comment: @hedgehog But how do you put a TreeViewItem into a HierachalDataTemplate? Isn't the HierachalDataTemplate sort of a TreeViewItem itself?

Comment: You dont. You take that code I gave you and put in Window.Resource. It is a style for TreeViewItem and when TreeViewItem is being created it will look up for its style. It will find it. Dont worry.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean selected when the textbox gets focused:

```
<TreeView VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProfileViewModel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                       IsKeyboardFocusWithin="{Binding IsSelected, 
                                               Mode=OneWayToSource}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Profiles}"
                  Header="Profiles"/>
    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Jobs}"
                  Header="Jobs"/>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: VS over here says "The property "IsKeyboardFocusWithin" does not have an accessible setter."